# Batch file commands to trigger Add/Remove "Repair" action?

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have an Outlook add-in which occasionally is forcibly deactivated by my IT department periodically.

I also have a batch file I run after logging in which accounts for various other discrepancies between how I want my computer configured and how IT does. I would like to be able to include a fix for this, too.

I can repair this manually by the following:

1. Open Add/Remove Programs
2. Right click on item (it's the [NoReplyAll](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/60860f41-88ab-4bb4-8104-765feca9cfed/) addin)
3. Select "Repair"

How can I do this through a batch file?

Comment: Deactivated or uninstalled ? Meaning are the files deleted or is it just the registry.

Comment: Its silly that they make those changes and give you enough privileges to undo them...

Comment: @tumchaaditya I'm not complaining. I more or less have full administrator rights which gives me all sorts of fun things to do with the registry to get around other group policies :) There are a few .reg files in a startup script I wrote let's just say, hehe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For installation, uninstallation or repair programs installed through `msi`, you may use `msiexec /?`.

Repair Your plugin with:

`msiexec /qn /f {93A8082F-E067-4F3C-8935-0BA903200F3B}`

or (with installer)

`msiexec /qn /f "NoReplyAll Add-In.msi"`

`/f` - states repair install

`/qn` - runs without GUI

Comment: +1 I have looked at the installation file of NoReplyAll and it is an extremely simple one. Reinstalling is indeed the best option.

Comment: Naturally it's been a full week and the addin hasn't been deactivated yet. I assume this will work though should it happen, thanks so much!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, this has been working great for me since you posted this - thanks much!